# How to make wkhtmltopdf work on Drupal

Tags: 7, files, theming

I have installed the drupal Print module, but have not been successful in getting wkhtmltopdf to work. The drupal print documentation is outdated and despite of a number of request to update it, it still is outdated. https://www.drupal.org/node/306882

CASE DESCRIPTION
In my case, I want to allow the creation of pdf versions of nodes. The Nodes have inline CSS (using Tinymce editor with Wysiwyg). I tried using Dompdf library, but the inline css is not being used for the created pdf.

I have read that wkhtmltopdf creates an internal browser that renders a html page, so that should be the ideal solution in this case.

However, after downloading the rpm file from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ into the sites/all/libraries folder of my website, and installing it using 
   rpm -Uvh wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-centos6-amd64.rpm
in my website, the library is not recognized, not visible in the status report page and not in the pdf configuration page /admin/config/user-interface/print/pdf

Comment: Have restarted your web server and made sure the installed executables have the correct permissions so that that the web server process has access to it?

Comment: Are you sure the library is installed in sites/all/libraries? As far as I recall, RPM install files in system directories.

Comment: I have restarted the website, the rpm has the correct permissions, the command line test to create a pdf of www.google.com was successful. But wkhtmltopdf is not visible as option in not in the pdf configuration page /admin/config/user-interface/print/pdf

Comment: Is this for D7 and D8?

Comment: This is for D7.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Yuri's answer, I wanted to provide more detail for how I solved this issue, where I couldn't resolve the following error:

> No PDF generation tool found! Please download a supported PHP PDF generation tool

1. install the [print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module
2. install pdf php handlers and libraries for your environment from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html; see note
3. create symlink in `sites/all/libraries/wkhtmltopdf` to library in server; make sure symlink is executable to the server `sudo chown -h [owner]`and `sudo chgrp -h [group]`
4. install and enable [phpwkhtmltopdf](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpwkhtmltopdf)
5. run `drush make --no-core -y sites/all/modules/contrib/phpwkhtmltopdf/phpwkhtmltopdf.make`
6. enable `print_pdf_wkhtmltopdf`
7. set up and customize; [see recommendations in this blog for more
   info](https://www.sitepoint.com/effective-pdf-generation-drupal/)

Note: My local dev environment is on a Mac OS X so I had to download and run the package, then create a symlink to `sites/all/libraries/wkhtmltopdf`from `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Sources:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2430561
- https://www.sitepoint.com/effective-pdf-generation-drupal/
- https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: Why do you need the print module?

Comment: Good question. I can only guess that I needed to use the print module for printer friendly pages and then needed the other stuff for it to work.